# Different segfaults for command line parsing by different compilers

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault, cygwin, mingw

I've been learning C by following through Zed Shaw's tutorial and ran into some issues on [this exercise](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex11.html).  Code is as follows

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i < argc) {
        printf("arg %d: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
        i++;
    }
    // section removed for brevity
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using Windows and don't like the hassle of virtualboxing so I've been running in Cygwin.  I have two compilers, one is the gcc that came with Cygwin, the other is the version (of gcc) that comes with mingw so I can use DrMemory.

I make the file (named ex11.c) like this

```
# Makefile
ex11: ex11.c
    gcc -o ex11.exe ex11.c
    i686-pc-mingw32-gcc.exe -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -ggdb -o ex11b.exe ex11.c

# Command Line
>>> make ex11
   ...
   etc
```

The command for the second one I got [here](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~cutler/classes/advancedgraphics/S13/memory_debugging.html).

```
$ gcc --version
gcc.exe (rubenvb-4.6.3) 4.6.3)
$ i686-pc-mingw32-gcc --version
i686-pc-mingw32-gcc (GCC) 4.7.3
```

Then when I run them (`./ex11` and `./ex11b`) I get issues.  Running the normal version (without the b) without command line arguments gives me a segfault.  Running with arguments gives me this output:

```
$ ./ex11 a
arg 0: a
arg 1: a
```

Running the mingw version (with b) I have no problems without command line arguments:

```
$ ./ex11b
arg 0: (null)
```

but then running the same with a command line argument (`$ ./ex11b a`) segfaults me.

Assembler output of the first

```
    .file   "ex11.c"
    .def    __main; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .section .rdata,"dr"
.LC0:
    .ascii "arg %d: %s\12\0"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .def    main;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .seh_proc   main
main:
    pushq   %rbp
    .seh_pushreg    %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    subq    $48, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 48
    .seh_setframe   %rbp, 48
    .seh_endprologue
    movl    %ecx, 16(%rbp)
    movq    %rdx, 24(%rbp)
    call    __main
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    jmp .L2
.L3:
    movq    24(%rbp), %rax
    addq    $72, %rax
    movq    (%rax), %rcx
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rax
    movl    -4(%rbp), %edx
    movq    %rcx, %r8
    movq    %rax, %rcx
    call    printf
    addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
.L2:
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    cmpl    16(%rbp), %eax
    jl  .L3
    movl    $0, %eax
    addq    $48, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
    .seh_endproc
    .def    printf; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
```

Assembler output of the second

```
    .file   "ex11.c"
    .def    ___main;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .section .rdata,"dr"
LC0:
    .ascii "arg %d: %s\12\0"
    .text
    .globl  _main
    .def    _main;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
_main:
LFB6:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $32, %esp
    call    ___main
    movl    $0, 28(%esp)
    jmp L2
L3:
    movl    12(%ebp), %eax
    addl    $36, %eax
    movl    (%eax), %eax
    movl    %eax, 8(%esp)
    movl    28(%esp), %eax
    movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
    movl    $LC0, (%esp)
    call    _printf
    addl    $1, 28(%esp)
L2:
    movl    28(%esp), %eax
    cmpl    8(%ebp), %eax
    jl  L3
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
LFE6:
    .def    _printf;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
```

I know what causes the segfault, I think.  I have `i` initialized to 0 so I'm sometimes trying to get a null value, which one doesn't like.  What I'm wondering is what about these compilers is different that they'll break like this.

I'm also curious how I could rewrite this so I can start at `i=0`

Comment: I've never seen such behavior. What versions of gcc are in use (add `--version` after the compiler executable name)? Also, please use `i686-pc-mingw32-gcc.exe`; `i686-pc-mingw32-g++.exe` is the C++ frontend.

Comment: Another helpful bit would be the assembler output. Adding `-S` would output it to whatever file you specified as the argument to the `-o` option.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune Both done, see updated question

Answer (score 4):

Your compilers or environment appear to be broken somehow. All the elements of the `argv[]` array must point to strings, and only `argv[argc]` must be `NULL`. If the program name is not available, then `argv[0]` must point to an empty string (`""`).

What you *can* do is test for `NULL` in your loop, but you really shouldn't have to:

```c
while(i < argc) {
    if (argv[i]) {
        printf("arg %d: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: I adjusted the command I use so that it compiles with a C compiler and the same issue occurs

Answer (score 1):

Your compilers appear to be generating incorrect addresses, specifically the calculation of the array offset for `argv` as shown in the 32-bit (i686) assembly code:

```
L3:
    movl    12(%ebp), %eax
    addl    $36, %eax
    movl    (%eax), %eax
    movl    %eax, 8(%esp) 
    movl    28(%esp), %eax 
    movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
...
call _printf
```

Detangling that mess, you end up with the following:

```
printf(..., i, argv[9]); //argv[9]
```

The `addl $1, 28(%esp)` instruction is the `i++` in your C code, so you can guess what the equivalents of `12(%ebp)` and `28(%esp)` are in your C code.

Anyway, the big picture is this: nothing is done with `argv[i]` because it is always `argv[9]` that is passed to `printf`. The `addl $36, %eax` should be `addl %edx, %eax`, assuming the `%edx` register was used to store the value of `i` before performing the add operation, which it isn't in the assembly code you provided.

In other words, your code isn't being compiled correctly with either compiler. Unfortunately I have no idea what is causing the problem. Have you tried using i686-pc-mingw32-gcc.exe outside of the Cygwin shell? Maybe your Cygwin installation is somehow messed up?

Comment: I tried using the mingw32 exe outside of the command line, it just flashed the command prompt and then it disappeared.  It could be Cygwin, I don't know how I'd check that though

Comment: To use it outside of the Cygwin shell, open a normal Windows command prompt and use the compiler. Of course, it must be in your PATH, so if you get an error message "No such file or directory", use `SET PATH=<directory_containing_the_i686_compiler>;%PATH%`. For example, I use `SET PATH=C:\mingw\bin;%PATH%` because C:\mingw\bin is where my x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe compiler is located. Setting the PATH will only affect that one command window though.